# Method will not match with nested type restrictions

Tags: julia, dispatch

I have this simple method which calculates the weighted average of a collection of vectors

```
function meanw{T <: Number}(x::AbstractArray{AbstractVector{T}, 1}, w::AbstractVector{T})
  x̄ = sum(x .* w)
  x̃ = map(z -> z - x̄, x)
  x̄, x̃
end
```

but the dispatch cannot match my method when I try to use it.

```
ERROR: `meanw` has no method matching meanw(::Array{Array{Float64,1},1}, ::Array{Float64,1})
```

I suspect that I have misunderstood how to use type restrictions when there is nesting involved. How should I rewrite this function to match my collections?

P.S.

I know vectors and arrays are the same thing but the differentiation makes it clearer how the function is used.

Comment: The StatsBase.jl package has a mean function which supports weights.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So if you rewrite your code to use the concrete Types it works

```
function meanw{T <: Number}(x::Array{Vector{T}, 1}, w::Vector{T})
  x̄ = sum(x .* w)
  x̃ = map(z -> z - x̄, x)
  x̄, x̃
end
```

this also works

```
function meanw{T <: Number}(x::Array{Vector{T}, 1}, w::AbstractVector{T})
  x̄ = sum(x .* w)
  x̃ = map(z -> z - x̄, x)
  x̄, x̃
end
```

this doesn't work

```
function meanw{T <: Number}(x::Array{AbstractVector{T}, 1}, w::AbstractVector{T})
  x̄ = sum(x .* w)
  x̃ = map(z -> z - x̄, x)
  x̄, x̃
end
```

and this does work again

```
function meanw{T <: Number}(x::AbstractArray{Vector{T}, 1}, w::AbstractVector{T})
  x̄ = sum(x .* w)
  x̃ = map(z -> z - x̄, x)
  x̄, x̃
end
```

the problem we have here is described in the Julia manual under [parametric types](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/types/#Parametric-Types-1)

> This last point is very important:
>
> Even though Float64 <: Real we DO NOT have Point{Float64} <:
>   Point{Real}.
>
> In other words, in the parlance of type theory, Julia’s type
>   parameters are invariant, rather than being covariant (or even
>   contravariant). This is for practical reasons: while any instance of
>   Point{Float64} may conceptually be like an instance of Point{Real} as
>   well, the two types have different representations in memory:

What actually does work is this

```
function meanw{T <: Number, V <: AbstractVector}(x::AbstractArray{V, 1}, w::AbstractVector{T})
  x̄ = sum(x .* w)
  x̃ = map(z -> z - x̄, x)
  x̄, x̃
end
```

but the real question is why do you want to do this? 
The Julia Compiler is clever enough even without type annotations to produce efficient code as long as the inputs are well-typed and the function itself is type-stable. Type annotations are only really needed for multiple-dispatch and as contract to specify what the function can actually handle, but this is notoriously difficult in Julia due to the extensive type system.

Comment: Sorry for the late accept. The answer did what I asked for but I think I realized that what I did was not the right thing. It is probably better to be less strict with the types in the future.

Answer (score 2):

The root problem is

```
julia> Vector{Vector} <: Vector{AbstractArray}
false
```

and you are passing in a vector of vectors. I'd rewrite this as

```
function meanw{T<:Number,S<:Number}(x::Vector{Array{T}}, w::Vector{S})
    x̄ = sum(x .* w)
    x̃ = map(z -> z - x̄, x)
    x̄, x̃
end
```

to allow for, say, `Float64` `x` and `Int` `w`. Alternatively don't restrict it all - its probably unnecessary anyway as it won't make it faster and is only a defensive coding thing.

Answer (score 1):

Julia is a fast-growing language and with each generation, new capabilities unveiled and some Q&As need review.

**IMPORTANT**

```
julia> VERSION
v"0.6.0-dev.2259"
```

One of the advanced features of Julia is its dispatching system. 
[(excellent reading about multiple dispatch)](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/StefanKarpinski/b8fe9dbb36c1427b9f22).
Now, because of [this merge](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/18457) (v0.6.0 2017-1-16) users could benefit from new capability of **triangular dispatching** [(read why is it useful?)](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/3766).
Here we need to address the problem of writing generic methods for two arguments:

1. A one dimensional array (general vector) of numbers `w`
2. A general array of general vectors of numbers `x`

@wallnuss's answer involves 4 methods that all work. Here is the first one:

`function meanw{T <: Number}(x::Array{Vector{T}, 1}, w::Vector{T})
    info("both are Vector for the same element-type: $T") 
end`

```
julia> meanw([[1],[2]], [1])
INFO: both are Vector for the same element-type: Int32
```

The above is **very specific** mainly because it doesn't cover different sub types of `AbstractVector` e.g.:

```
julia> (typeof(spzeros(3)) |> supertype |> supertype) <: AbstractVector #=> true
```

So the second one is defined:

`function meanw{T <: Number}(x::Array{Vector{T}, 1}, w::AbstractVector{T})
    info("an Array of Vectors and an AbstractVector sub-type both with the same element-type: $T") # 
end`

With the above:

```
julia> meanw([[1.],[2]], spzeros(3))
INFO: an Array of Vectors and an AbstractVector sub-type both with the same element-type: Float64
```

And a more general method:

`function meanw{T <: Number}(x::AbstractArray{Vector{T}, 1}, w::AbstractVector{T})
    info("an AbstractVector subtype of Vectors and an AbstractVector sub-type both with the same element-type $T")
end`

Even after the latest method, some scenarios isn't fulfilled:

```
julia> meanw([spzeros(3) for i=1:3], spzeros(3)) #=> Error
julia> meanw([[1],[2]],[1.]) #=> Error
```

So all the above are **more specific** than may need.

`function meanw{T <: Number, V <: AbstractVector}(x::AbstractArray{V, 1}, w::AbstractVector{T})
  info("an AbstractVector of AbstractVector sub-type with Any element and an AbstractVector sub-type of Number")
end`

Seems that the last method covers all possible scenarios, but it is **more general** than may need e.g.:

```
julia> meanw([[""],[2]],[1.]) #=> Not enough restriction for element type of first AbstractVector
INFO: an AbstractVector of AbstractVector sub-type with Any element and an AbstractVector sub-type of Number
```

Now with the new triangular feature we could write:

`function meanw{T <: Number, V <: AbstractVector{T}}(x::AbstractArray{V, 1}, w::AbstractVector{T})
  info("an AbstractVector of AbstractVector sub-type and an AbstractVector subtype both for same sub-type of Number (triangular)")
end`

Check methods precedence:

```
julia> methods(meanw)
# 5 methods for generic function "meanw":
meanw{T<:Number}(x::Array{Array{T,1},1}, w::Array{T,1}) in Main at REPL[1]:2
meanw{T<:Number}(x::Array{Array{T,1},1}, w::AbstractArray{T,1}) in Main at REPL[22]:2
meanw{T<:Number}(x::AbstractArray{Array{T,1},1}, w::AbstractArray{T,1}) in Main at REPL[24]:2
meanw{T<:Number,V<:AbstractArray{T<:Number,1}}(x::AbstractArray{V,1}, w::AbstractArray{T,1}) in Main at REPL[41]:2 
meanw{T<:Number,V<:(AbstractArray{T,1} where T)}(x::AbstractArray{V,1}, w::AbstractArray{T,1}) in Main at REPL[39]:2
```

The latest method have taken the 4th seat because it is more specific that its former.

```
julia> meanw([spzeros(3) for i=1:3], spzeros(3))
INFO: an AbstractVector of AbstractVector sub-type and an AbstractVector subtype both for a same sub-type of Number (triangular)
```

But `meanw([[2],[2]],[1.])` is still directed to the more general method (5th). Let define another method:

`function meanw{T <: Number, W <: Number, V <: AbstractVector{W}}(x::AbstractArray{V, 1}, w::AbstractVector{T})
  info("an AbstractVector of AbstractVector sub-type and an AbstractVector sub-type both for Number (triangular)")
end`

```
julia> meanw([[2],[2]],[1.])
INFO: an AbstractVector of AbstractVector sub-type and an AbstractVector sub-type both for Number (triangular)
```