# Parametric type not working as expected in Julia

Tags: julia

I am pretty new to Julia and this is driving me nuts:

```
type MyType{T<:Number}
  x::T
  y::T
end
Float64 <: Number # this is true
MyType{Float64} <: MyType{Number} #this is for some reason false
```

I would of course expect that, if I created two concrete types derived from the same parametric type one by using an abstract type as the parameter and the other by using concrete type that is a subtype of the abstract type used for the first derivation, the type derived using the concrete type would be a subtype of the one derived using the abstract type.

That sentence took me a while to compose. Hopefully it is intelligible.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25490364/method-will-not-match-with-nested-type-restrictions/25493927#25493927

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the expected behavior: Types in Julia are invariant rather than covariant or contravariant. Quoting from the docs:

> Julia's type parameters are invariant, rather than being covariant (or
> even contravariant). This is for practical reasons: while any instance
> of Point{Float64} may conceptually be like an instance of Point{Real}
> as well, the two types have different representations in memory:
>
> An instance of Point{Float64} can be represented compactly and
> efficiently as an immediate pair of 64-bit values;    An instance of
> Point{Real} must be able to hold any pair of instances of Real. Since
> objects that are instances of Real can be of arbitrary size and
> structure, in practice an instance of Point{Real} must be represented
> as a pair of pointers to individually allocated Real objects.

See the [manual](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/types/)